# Eclipse window "workspace launcher" for selecting a workspace is invisble under ubunt 14.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

if I start my eclipse 4.4 (latest) and I accidentally click on a different window under ubuntu 14.04 during this phase of eclipse startup, the windows "workspace launcher" which asks to "select a workspace" gets hidden completely.

[image: Workspace launcher]

I cannot switch neither with the task list (alt-tab) nor with the preview (windows-key) back to it. I have to minimize one by one of the top applications to get back to the window "Workspace launcher".

Can someone tell me what I have to change? To see the windows again as a usual process?

Answer (score 0):

Workspace launcher cannot be minimised or maximised. If it is made so then it will appear in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> list .

If you are using Unity desktop environment then check this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156376/how-to-get-a-dialog-box-back-to-front). I am using gnome classic <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> is not working for me.